# Android - Kotlin - Retrofit2 | @Query not working

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to get a parameter in my API request url.

If I set it like this it works

```
interface SteamApiService{
    @GET("appdetails?appids=218620")
    fun getGame(): Deferred<Map<String, GameDetailedWrapper2>>
}
```

I now want to use a variable I put in the getGame()
As far as I can tell you're supposed to do this with the @Query but I can't seem to get it working.
I also can't figure out if there's a way to see the actual call you make (that'd have helped me debug)
Beneath this is my full ApiService with the @Query I tried (among others)

My ApiService

```
package com.example.projectandroid.data.network

import com.example.projectandroid.model.Game
import com.example.projectandroid.model.GameDetailed
import com.example.projectandroid.model.GameDetailedWrapper
import com.example.projectandroid.model.GameDetailedWrapper2
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineCallAdapterFactory
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
import kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Path
import retrofit2.http.Query

private const val BASE_URL_STEAM = "https://store.steampowered.com/api/"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    //.add(ResponseGetGamesAdapter())
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

//OkhttpClient for building http request url
private val tmdbClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(tmdbClient)
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL_STEAM)
    .build()


interface SteamApiService{
    @GET("appdetails")
    fun getGame(@Query("appids") appid:String): Deferred<Map<String, GameDetailedWrapper2>>

}



object SteamApi {
    val retrofitService: SteamApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(SteamApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, fully deleting the app seems to have fixed that...